# How to do service discovery for Spring Boot REST endpints

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If I have multiple Spring Boot embedded tomcat containers and each can have service endpoints like

```
http://localhost:8080/employeeSelfService/getDetails
http://localhost:8081/employeeSelfService/getDetails
```

How can do load balancing using 2 micro services such that clients can hit any of the URL's mentioned based on some load balancing startegy

One option thats come to my mind is to use NetFlix Curator (or) have a apache webserver acting as reverse proxy but with apache, when you create new instances of your services, you will have have an entry of that service as a member in httpd.conf

Does Spring Boot provides any service discovery and load balancing mechanism ?

Comment: The reason of opting such a Micro services is that, services can scale  up or down, and register themselves as part of the entire suite of services. So one would need service register & discovery and also a load balancing mechanism in case if you have multiple instances for same services. Cloud Foundry is one such example where you can scale your application instances. So the Java build pack used for pushing WARs can be used even for JAR executable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot does not provide this feature, as it is already usually provided by a reverse proxy  such as apache/nginx running in front of the Spring Boot server.

See here for an example here how the commercial version of nginx provides the functionality of [dynamically scaling and reducing the upstream nodes](http://nginx.com/products/on-the-fly-reconfiguration/).

So in this case it's for the dynamic instance, in this case the Spring Boot process to signal it's presence/unregister itself to the upstream server at initialization/shutdown.

See [here](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/load-balancer) how to do so in the case of nginx, this procedure will be different from server to server.

Answer (score 2):

Arguably it's not really an application's role to manage its own load-balancing, and Spring Boot focuses on the implementation of an application (or service, equivalently). We have been thinking about whether we could provide features in Spring (Boot or otherwise) to make it easy to write your own load-balancer, or service registry app, but even then I don't think that was what the question was really about (or was it?).

If I interpret the question, and the example use case, literally, I would say that the most natural answer is an out-of-the-box reverse proxy solution (as the other answers pointed out). I also note that such a reverse proxy is an essential and natural part of a PaaS solution, so if you need it to "just work" and don't want to know about the details, PaaS would be a natural path (e.g. see [cloudfoundry](http://cloudfoundry.org/index.html) as an example of such a solution that I happen to have worked on).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Spring Boot has not inherit support for load-balancing. Just to add to the list of available solutions for load-balancing, [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) are the instructions to configure an Apache for load-balancing.